# Question on completion compactness

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

I am reading a proof on completions on the internet. I want to prove that the completion of $\mathbf{Q}[x]$ with respect to the $I$-adic topology with $I=(x)$ is not compact. However, I can not fill in the details of the proof of (i)-> (ii) here. How does this argument "cover $\widehat{R}$ by infinitely many disjoint neighbourhoods homeomorphic to $\hat{I}$" work?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How are the neighbourhoods in the $I$-adic topology defined?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma a basis of neighbourhoods is given by $I^n=(x^n)$ in my case

Comment: A base of neighbourhoods for which point?

Comment: Suppose $\hat R/\hat I=\{x_{\lambda}\hat I\mid \lambda\in \Lambda\}$. Then $\hat R=\sqcup_{\lambda} x_{\lambda}\hat I$. I don't know much about the $I$-adic topology, but I expect $x_{\lambda}\hat I$ to be homeomorphic to $\hat I$.

Comment: Where have you found this proof? Could you provide a reference?